# Force PDF to open in new window/tab

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, search, jquery, pdf

I am using SharePoint Foundation 2010 and attempting to have my PDFs open in a new tab or window. I have been able to get this to work from document libraries by using jQuery. You can see this code below. One of the reason I am using this is to avoid the user being prompted for credentials every time they open the a PDF.

```
$("a[target!='_blank'][href$='.pdf']").attr("target", "_blank").removeAttr("onclick");
```

I also have Search Server Express 2010 setup on this server. When I try to run this same jQuery code on the results.aspx page it responds different. It is forcing a download of the PDF (the natural action) as well as opening it in a new tab/window (as I have added). I tried to add similar code to this below to prevent the downloading of the PDF. I just want it to open in a new window/tab.

```
 $("a[target!='_blank'][href$='.pdf']").attr("target", "_blank").removeAttr("onclick").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

If anybody has any suggestions or pointers, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution and it works well for me. I do not have the Search Server Express as part of my SP Foundation 2010 installation, so I can't answer whether this will have any affect with it. This is also a jQuery solution, albeit a little longer.

This code should be places before the closing  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function ()
                {
                    // has to be on an interval for grouped doc libraries
                    // where the actual links are loaded only once a group
                    // is expanded
                    setInterval(
                    function ()
                        {
                        $("a[onclick*='return DispEx'][target!='_blank']")
                        .attr("target", "_blank")
                        .removeAttr("onclick");

                        // document type icons
                        $("td.ms-vb-icon>img[onclick]:not([documentUrl])")
                        .click(function (e)
                            {
                                window.open($(this).attr("documentUrl"), "_blank");
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                e.preventDefault();
                                return false;
                            })
                        .each(function ()
                            {
                                $(this).attr(
                                    "documentUrl",
                                    $.trim(String($(this).attr("onclick"))
                                    .split("=")[1]
                                    .replace(/["'{}]/g, "")
                                    .split(";")[0])
                                );
                                this.onclick = null;
                            });
                        },
                    500
                    );
                }
        );
</script>
```